# Uncaught TypeError: theme is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

This is my settings.js where I get the error from because theme is undefined

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Switch } from 'react-native';
import { useTheme } from '../utils/ThemeContext';

function Settings() {
  const { theme, toggleDarkMode } = useTheme();

  const handleToggleSwitch = () => {
    toggleDarkMode();
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <View
        style={{
          backgroundColor: theme.headerBackgroundColor || 'orange',
          paddingLeft: 16,
          paddingTop: 12,
          paddingBottom: 12,
        }}
      >
        {headerTitleComponent('Settings')}
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 24, color: 'white' }}>Settings</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={{ padding: 16 }}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, marginBottom: 16 }}>Dark Mode</Text>
        <Switch
          value={theme.isDarkMode}
          onValueChange={handleToggleSwitch}
          trackColor={{ false: '#767577', true: '#81b0ff' }}
          thumbColor={theme.isDarkMode ? '#f5dd4b' : '#f4f3f4'}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

export default Settings;
```

This is my tabnavigator.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import MovieScreen from './MovieScreen';
import Settings from '../screens/Settings';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function TabNavigator() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}
      tabBarOptions={{
        activeTintColor: 'orange',
        style: {
          backgroundColor: 'orange',
        },
      }}
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name='Movies'
        component={MovieScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Movies',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <Ionicons name='film' color={color} size={size} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name='Settings'
        component={Settings}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Settings',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <Ionicons name='settings' color={color} size={size} />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

export default TabNavigator;
```

This is my app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { ThemeProvider } from '../utils/ThemeContext'; // Update the import path
import TabNavigator from './TabNavigator';

const lightTheme = {
  backgroundColor: '#fff',
  textColor: '#000',
  headerBackgroundColor: 'orange',
};

const darkTheme = {
  backgroundColor: '#333',
  textColor: '#fff',
  headerBackgroundColor: '#222',
};

function App() {
  const [isDarkMode, setIsDarkMode] = React.useState(false);

  const theme = isDarkMode ? darkTheme : lightTheme;

  return (
    <ThemeProvider>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <TabNavigator />
      </NavigationContainer>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is my themecontext:

```
// ThemeContext.js
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';

const ThemeContext = createContext();

export const ThemeProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [isDarkMode, setIsDarkMode] = useState(false);

  const toggleDarkMode = () => {
    setIsDarkMode((prevMode) => !prevMode);
  };

  const theme = {
    isDarkMode,
    toggleDarkMode,
    // Add other theme properties here
  };

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={theme}>{children}</ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useTheme = () => {
  const context = useContext(ThemeContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error('useTheme must be used within a ThemeProvider');
  }
  return context;
};
```

I get this error because theme is undefined at theme.headerBackgroundColor

I'm trying to make a switch button in my settings screen so I can change my app to darkmode/lightmode.

Comment: there is no `theme` property in your context object? it should be like `const theme = {
    isDarkMode,
    toggleDarkMode,
    theme:{...},
    // Add other theme properties here
  };`